# Cannot resolve htaccess RewriteEngine not allowed here

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Question is: How do I resolve "RewriteEngine not allowed here".

I've looked at this for a couple of hours and cannot resolve it, even after following the repeated instructions to include 'Allow from all' in the directory configuration.

OSX 10.9
Server version: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix)
mod_rewrite is enabled

httpd config:

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apps/site/code">
    Options All MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
```

I still get:

/usr/local/apps/site/code/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that's the directory is being read from there? Are you using any Vhosts? if so that will typically be inside the virtualhost directive. Also it appears you are mixing different versions of Apache. `Require all granted` is for Apache 2.4 so you need to remove that line.

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: @anubhava DocumentRoot is same as the directory

Comment: @anubhava Yep. LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: Hmm I guess it is better to show your complete `httpd.conf` where rest of the directives are placed.

Comment: I think the issue is now resolved. I was trying to get a client's very old php app running locally on Friday. Apparently their single aws instance is running httpd 2.4.x and my local instance was 2.2.x. I finally completed the upgrade to Yosemite this weekend which comes with 2.4.9 internally and I'm no longer hitting the htaccess problem. I thought I had tested this Friday by installing 2.4.9 from Homebrew but got the problem too. Regardless, all seems well now. Thanks for the help.